# How can i refresh data table after updating the data and retain on the pagination page

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, laravel-5

I used ajax.reload(), but it is not working.

I try the other method to refresh the data but how can i stay on the current pagination table after data been edited.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/test',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (html) {
                $('#group').html(html);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
```

I able to refresh the page if using above method but it will always return back to first pagination table. Anyone got idea how to make it how can i stay on the current pagination table after data been edited?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get your current page (example: 3).
When you call the function to refresh the content, you need to pass your current page as parameter. For example:

```
var myCurrentPage = 3; 
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/test',
    dataType: 'HTML',
    data: {page: myCurrentPage}
    success: function (html) {
        $('#group').html(html);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

The var could be dynamic using input hidden or some element attribute

I hope that you have understood the logic. Tell me if not.

Comment: i used var info = table.page.info(); to get the current page of datatable. is it just pass the page number will do?

Comment: Please provide the code that you use to pagination. You need to call this function. Example: if you click in next page you'll go to page 2. You need to save this number (page 2), when you need to refresh the content, call the pagination function passing 'page 2' as parameter. This way the content will loaded in your current page.

Answer (score 0):

> Im using this for stay on Page (before reload). "bStateSave" : true,
>   I hope this will answer your reload page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#users').DataTable({
        "bStateSave" : true,
        // "searching" : false,
        "columns": [
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "name"},
            {"data": "phone"},
            {"data": "fax"},
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url: 'demo.php',
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
```